# iOS 8.3 doesnt seem to be returning all characteristics for service

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

In my CBPeripheralDelegate I have the following methods

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {

    if (error) {
        DDLogError(@"Error discovering services: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
    // Loop through the newly filled peripheral.services array, just in case there's more than one.
    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        NSArray *uids = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kSendDataCharacteristicUUID],
                          [CBUUID UUIDWithString:kReceiveDataCharacteristicUUID]];
        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:uids
                                 forService:service];
    }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error{
    // Deal with errors (if any)
    if (error) {
        DDLogError(@"Error discovering characteristics: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }

    // Again, we loop through the array, just in case.
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kReceiveDataCharacteristicUUID]]) {
            _receiveCharacteristic = characteristic;
            [_peripheral setNotifyValue:YES
                      forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }

        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:kSendDataCharacteristicUUID]]) {
            _sendCharacteristic = characteristic;
        }

    }

    if (_sendCharacteristic && _receiveCharacteristic) {
        [self allServicesDiscovered];
    }
}
```

However, since ios 8.3, the "kReceiveDataCharacteristicUUID" characteristic is no longer discovered.

I have verified this with and external BLE discovery app, and it gives the same.\

Is there some way to manually add a non discovered service?

Edit: here is the hardware debug log from our engineers. It looks like ios is starting 1 bit later than what it used to.

Android (Note ATT starts at 0x0003)
[image: low level android comms log]

iOS 8.3 (Note ATT starts at 0x0004)
[image: low level ios comms log]

Comment: just to test, you may consider discovering all of the characteristics for the service.  Set discoverCharacteristics to nil and see if didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService is called with your UUID.

Comment: Yeah. Have tried that but same results

Comment: Are none of them not discovered, of just one? Does LightBlue sees it?

Comment: Only one characteristic is discovered. Lightblue shows the same

Comment: What's the other device? Could it be that your other device that you try to connect is malfunctioning?

Comment: we build our own devices. Every single one of our test devices is no longer reporting all characteristics as of ios8.3, so its not a device problem. Also, the device shows all the characteristics when i connect to it from android

Comment: Rdar://20548366 reported

Comment: @ZayinKrige Please, can you tell me if you have found why only 1 characteristics is discovered? I am in the exact same situation that you was

Comment: @sdespont In the end I asked our engineers to change the ble protocol to cater for this weirdness and that solved the problem

Comment: @ZayinKrige Thanks for your answer. On my side, I just made an upgrade to the last version of IOS and it is working.